# crtbegin_so.o missing for android toolchain (custom build)

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, gdc

I have compiled gdc together with gcc using the android build-gcc.sh script, and have included a new stub in build/core/definitions.mk to deal with D language files as a part of the build process. I know things are compiling OK at this point, but my problem is linking:

When I build a project, I get this error:

```
ld: crtbegin_so.o: No such file: No such file or directory
```

This is true  for regular c-only projects as well. Now I ran a quick *find* in my build directory, and found that the file (crtbegin_so.o) does exist within the sysroot I specified when I compiled gcc (or rather, when build-gcc.sh built it).

- What are some things I could look for to find a solution to this problem?
- Would copying the files locally and linking directly to them be a decent solution in the 
  interim?
- Why would ld (or collect2) be trying to include these for a gdc (D Language) linkage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400124/cant-run-sample-rhodes-application solved it for me :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue arises on NDK r7c for linux as well.

I found that the toolchain ignores the platform location *($NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/)* and searches for it in the toolchain path, which is incorrect.

However, as the toolchain also searches for the file in the current directory, one solution is to symlink the correct platform crtbegin_so.o and crtend_so.o into the source directory:

`cd src && ln -s NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.a`

`cd src && ln -s NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtend_so.a`

Thus your second point should work out (where you can do a symlink, instead of a copy)

**NOTE 1:**This assumes that the code is being compiled for API8 (Android 2.2) using the NDK. Please alter the path to the correct path as per your requirement.

**NOTE 2:**Configure flags used:

```
./configure \
--host=arm-linux-androideabi \
CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
CPPFLAGS="-I$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/" \
CFLAGS="-nostdlib" \
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/ -L$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/" \
LIBS="-lc"
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Now I can build gdc against the android toolchain.

Answer (score 6):

I have found that adding `--sysroot=$(SYSROOT)` to the compiler options fixes the error:

> cannot open crtbegin_so.o: No such file or directory

from my makefile...

```
CC= $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc -fvisibility-hidded $(INC) $(LIB) -shared
```

Note: this assumes that the setenv-android.sh has been run to setup the environment
`$. ./setenv-android.sh`

Comment: In VS2019, as this is part of the linker phase I needed to add `--sysroot="$(SysrootLink)"` to the linker command line options

Answer (score 2):

In my case quotes were missing from sysroot path.
When I changed

```
--sysroot=${ANDROID_NDK}\platforms\android-17\arch-arm
```

to

```
--sysroot="${ANDROID_NDK}\platforms\android-17\arch-arm"
```

the project was compiled and linked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue in two separate cases:

1. during building [`boost`](https://github.com/boostorg) for android
2. during using [`android-cmake`](https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake) project.

Once I have switched to `standalone toolchain` issue gone, here is example of command which prepare `standalone toolchain`

```
$NDK_ROOT/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --install-dir=android-toolchain --ndk-dir=$NDK_ROOT --system=darwin-x86_64 --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9
```

**Boost specific**

for boost you need specify `--sysroot` several times in your `jam`

```
<compileflags>--sysroot=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
<linkflags>--sysroot=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
```