# cross-compiling for android on linux. what is the target?

Tags: android, c, linux

I am trying to cross compile some linux tools for android using a linux machine. The general steps for compiling are

```
./configure
make
```

Now the configure file supports using the `$CC` variable as well as setting the target using `--target` option. But I am not sure what argument to use.

The processor information is

> AArch64 Processor rev 1 (aarch64)

So do I use `aarch64`? But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13710550/3395716) says I should be using `arm`? But it also uses android NDK which I don't have.

So what is the correct argument for `--target` option? Or should I use CC variable?

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand from here http://www.arm.com/products/processors/armv8-architecture.php aarch64 is compatible with 32bits so if you are targeting only the new 64 bits arm processors you can use aarch64, but if you also want 32bit for older processors you have to use arm.

Comment: Thanks. BTW is it compulsory that I set $CC to the aarch64 specific compiler(that would be `aarch64-gcc` I guess) or can I use the gcc's `-mcpu`option and do something like `gcc -mcpu=aarch64`?

Comment: Did you mean incompatible instead of compatible?

Comment: I wouldn't set CC unless it have a problem , you should be fine setting -mcpu=aarch64 or -march=aarch64

Comment: Compatible, from the article says 64 bit amr support 32bit, thats what i understand