# After NDK22 upgrade the build fails with "cannot open crtbegin_so.o / crtend_so.o" error

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, llvm

My app is using Android SDK and NDK. Until recently I was using SDK27 and NDK17c and all was working just fine. Then I decided to update my app and switched to SDK29 and NDK22 and the hell broke loose.

After taking into account the NDK directory structure changes and getting rid of all the remnants of GCC I was able to compile my .so library but during the build, there is this error:

```
19:38:58 **** Incremental Build of configuration android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a for project MyProjectJNI ****
make all 
Building target: ../../../../../../bin/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/libMyProjectJNI.so
Invoking: LLVM Clang C++ linker
clang++ -v -L"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin" -L"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\aarch64-linux-android\29" -L"../../../../../../bin/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/" -L"D:\Projects\Libs\boost_1_67_0/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/lib/" -L"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a" -L"D:\Projects\Libs\boost_1_67_0/lib/" -L"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x" --sysroot="C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/" -target aarch64-linux-android29 -shared -std=c++11 -O1 --no-undefined -Wl,-verbose -o "../../../../../../bin/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/libMyProjectJNI.so"  ./BaseJNI.bc ./CalibrationJNI.bc ./UtilsJNI.bc ./dllmain.bc   -lMyOtherLib -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lboost_atomic -lboost_chrono -ljnigraphics -llog
clang version 3.7.0 (tags/RELEASE_370/final)
Target: aarch64--linux-android
Thread model: posix
 "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple aarch64--linux-android29 -emit-obj -disable-free -main-file-name BaseJNI.bc -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 1 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -fuse-init-array -target-cpu generic -target-feature +neon -target-abi aapcs -backend-option -aarch64-fix-cortex-a53-835769=1 -v -dwarf-column-info -resource-dir "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.7.0" -O1 -std=c++11 -fdebug-compilation-dir "D:\\Projects\\Development\\trunk\\Host\\dev\\src\\MyProjectJNI\\android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -mstackrealign -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -fno-signed-char -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -o "C:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\BaseJNI-9a764d.o" -x ir ./BaseJNI.bc
clang -cc1 version 3.7.0 based upon LLVM 3.7.0 default target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
 "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple aarch64--linux-android29 -emit-obj -disable-free -main-file-name CalibrationJNI.bc -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 1 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -fuse-init-array -target-cpu generic -target-feature +neon -target-abi aapcs -backend-option -aarch64-fix-cortex-a53-835769=1 -v -dwarf-column-info -resource-dir "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.7.0" -O1 -std=c++11 -fdebug-compilation-dir "D:\\Projects\\Development\\trunk\\Host\\dev\\src\\MyProjectJNI\\android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -mstackrealign -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -fno-signed-char -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -o "C:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\CalibrationJNI-cc675c.o" -x ir ./CalibrationDataJNI.bc
clang -cc1 version 3.7.0 based upon LLVM 3.7.0 default target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
 "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple aarch64--linux-android29 -emit-obj -disable-free -main-file-name UtilsJNI.bc -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 1 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -fuse-init-array -target-cpu generic -target-feature +neon -target-abi aapcs -backend-option -aarch64-fix-cortex-a53-835769=1 -v -dwarf-column-info -resource-dir "C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.7.0" -O1 -std=c++11 -fdebug-compilation-dir "D:\\Projects\\Development\\trunk\\Host\\dev\\src\\MyProjectJNI\\android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -mstackrealign -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -fno-signed-char -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -o "C:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\UtilsJNI-6102ad.o" -x ir ./CalibrationJNI
clang -cc1 version 3.7.0 based upon LLVM 3.7.0 default target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
 "C:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk\\22.1.7171670\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\aarch64-linux-android\\bin\\ld.exe" "--sysroot=C:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk\\22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/" --eh-frame-hdr -m aarch64linux -shared -o ../../../../../../bin/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/libMyProjectJNI.so crtbegin_so.o "-LC:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk\\22.1.7171670\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\bin" "-LC:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk\\22.1.7171670\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\sysroot\\usr\\lib\\aarch64-linux-android\\29" -L../../../../../../bin/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/ "-LD:\\Projects\\Libs\\boost_1_67_0/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/lib/" "-LC:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk\\22.1.7171670/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a" "-LD:\\Projects\\Libs\\boost_1_67_0/lib/" "-LC:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk\\22.1.7171670/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x" "-LC:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk\\22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot//usr/lib" --no-undefined -verbose "C:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\BaseFrameJNI-9a764d.o" "C:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\CalibrationJNI-cc675c.o" "C:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\UtilsJNI-09f434.o" "C:\\Users\\UserPro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\dllmain-63e5e7.o" -lMyOtherLib -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lboost_atomic -lboost_chrono -ljnigraphics -llog -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc -ldl -lc -lgcc -ldl crtend_so.o
ld: crtbegin_so.o
ld: error: cannot open crtbegin_so.o: No such file or directory
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Temp\BaseJNI-9a764d.o
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Temp\CalibrationJNI-cc675c.o
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Temp\UtilsJNI-09f434.o
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Temp\dllmain-63e5e7.o
ld: ../../../../../../bin/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/liblMyOtherLib.so
ld: D:\Projects\Libs\boost_1_67_0/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/lib/libboost_system.a
ld: D:\Projects\Libs\boost_1_67_0/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/lib/libboost_filesystem.a
ld: D:\Projects\Libs\boost_1_67_0/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/lib/libboost_thread.a
ld: D:\Projects\Libs\boost_1_67_0/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/lib/libboost_atomic.a
ld: D:\Projects\Libs\boost_1_67_0/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/lib/libboost_chrono.a
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\aarch64-linux-android\29\libjnigraphics.so
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\aarch64-linux-android\29\liblog.so
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\aarch64-linux-android\29\libstdc++.so
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\aarch64-linux-android\29\libm.so
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x\libgcc.a
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\aarch64-linux-android\29\libdl.so
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\aarch64-linux-android\29\libc.so
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x\libgcc.a
ld: C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\aarch64-linux-android\29\libdl.so
ld: crtend_so.o
ld: error: cannot open crtend_so.o: No such file or directory
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [makefile:53: ../../../../../../bin/android_ndk22_android-29-arm64-v8a/libMyProjectJNI.so] Error 1
```

The files that the linker cannot find, **crtbegin_so.o** and **crtend_so.o**, are definitely here:
C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\aarch64-linux-android\29\

I know that the major change between ndk17 and ndk22 is that

> "Clang, binutils, the sysroot, and other toolchain pieces are now all
> installed to $NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/ and Clang will
> automatically find them. "

It looks to me like the linker was able to automatically find .so libraries but cannot find .o objects and is ignoring all paths I supply. Has anybody else encountered this problem? Any suggestions on how to solve it?

UPDATE: I respectfully disagree with the editing of the question. The switching from ndk17 to ndk22 includes switching from GCC to LLVM and probably the problem lies somewhere there.

UPDATE2
My clang++ command-line options for compiler:

```
-DNDEBUG 
-I"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include" 
-I"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android" 
-I"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/sources/android/cpufeatures" 
-I"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/sysroot/usr/include" 
-I"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include" 
-I"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android" 
-I"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/29" 
-I"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi" 
-I../../../include -I../../CommonUtilities 
-I"$(BOOST_PATH)" -I../../../../../../Common/include -O2 -emit-llvm -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -target aarch64-linux-android -std=c++0x
```

and for linker:

```
-v 
-L"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin" 
-L"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\sysroot\usr\lib\aarch64-linux-android\29" 
-L"../../../../../../bin/android_ndk23_android-29-arm64-v8a/" 
-L"D:\Projects\Libs\boost_1_67_0/android_ndk23_android-29-arm64-v8a/lib/" 
-L"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a" 
-L"D:\Projects\Libs\boost_1_67_0/lib/" 
-L"C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x" 
--sysroot="C:\Users\UserPro\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk\22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/" 
-target aarch64-linux-android -shared -std=c++11 -O1 --no-undefined -Wl,-verbose
```

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881164/crtbegin-so-o-missing-for-android-toolchain-custom-build)

Comment: @Shark Thanks, I have seen this, copying the files solves the problem indeed, however it looks like a workaround, not a real solution.

Comment: I'm wondering this: what does it matter if the object files are in `toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/...` if you're building for `aarch64--linux-android` arch. Any particular reason you didn't post the full build command, or am i just blind and don't see it in the log?  I see these two things: 1) `clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple aarch64--linux-android29 ` and 2) `clang -cc1 version 3.7.0 based upon LLVM 3.7.0 default target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu`. So why the windows/linux mixup? Is it intentional?

Comment: Perhaps you have a typo, and you want to build for `aarch64-linux-android` instead?

Comment: @Shark Thanks for bringing it to my attention. Now, that you have mentioned it, I don't know where this default target comes from. I checked and rechecked all projects setting, there is no mention of windows-gnu/ I am compiling on windows for android.  I will add my command lines for compiler and linker to my answer.

Comment: Stupid remark but - since you're likely working with makefiles, try using anything other than windows for interacting with them. IMO, makefiles on windows are the biggest pain ever.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get it.  "Anything other than windows" - like what?

Comment: But do try to find out where it's getting these two from: 1) `Target: aarch64--linux-android` and 2) `aarch64--linux-android29`

Comment: i always use a linux virtual machine for any sort of crosscompiling or NDK work. makes life much easier (for me). because in this particular case, you could just `grep` for these two things and see where they're coming from. no such thing on windows without weird grep-like programs (like WinGREP i think)

Comment: I see your point, but it will take some time to set up. I will try to understand this weird default target and will update.

Comment: yes, takes about a day. good part is - once setup, thats it. it's good forever :D

Comment: I stuck. Please can u point me where did u copy crtbegin_so.o and crtend_so.o as @Shark suggested? Can't succeed in linking

Comment: @SergeySalnikov see the answer I posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using -nostartfiles option. Worked for me